# Generator for the collatz conjecture sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, generator, collatz-sequence

I tried to write this code as concisely as possible. Is this the best way to do it?

```
def collatz(n):
    """
    Generator for collatz sequence beginning with n

    >>> list(collatz(10))
    [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
    """
    while n != 1:
        n = n / 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3*n + 1
        yield int(n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only improvement I see here is to divide **`n`** by 2 using **`//`** (since we are dealing with Python 3.x) and to remove the explicit conversion to int (**`int(n)`**):

```
while n != 1:
    n = n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3*n + 1
    yield n
```

Also, I suggest you put a single space before and after the multiplication operator in **`3*n`**, so that it becomes **`3 * n`**.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `while n > 1`, just in case someone tries to call this function with `n=0` or even a negative `n`.

Comment: Along those lines OP should probably mention in the docstring that `n` is a positive integer.

Answer (score 4):

I expect `collatz(1)` to produce `1`. Rather, it generates an empty sequence. So, in my opinion, the function should immediately `yield n` before the loop.

Comment: You're right, that was an oversight