# Efficient solution to Project Euler 14 (Longest Collatz sequence)

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, collatz-sequence

This is an iterative review. I asked for reviews on a Collatz sequence generator [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144801/generator-for-the-collatz-conjecture-sequence). I tried to address all of the suggestions that were made.

I've added a new function `get_longest_collatz(n)`, which can be used to solve Project Euler problem 14 (the question states: which number under a million has the longest Collatz sequence?)

The solution makes use of memoization.

```
def collatz(n):
    """
    Generator for collatz sequence beginning with n.
    n must be 0, 1, 2 ...

    >>> list(collatz(1))
    [1]

    >>> list(collatz(10))
    [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
    """
    yield n
    while n > 1:
        n = n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3 * n + 1
        yield n


def get_longest_collatz(n):
    """
    Returns the number less than n with the longest collatz sequence.

    >>> get_longest_collatz(1000)
    871
    """
    lengths = {} # Keys are natural numbers, values are lengths of collatz sequence
    for i in range(n):
        for count, x in enumerate(collatz(i)):
            if x in lengths:
                # The sequence length for x has already been found
                lengths[i] = count + lengths[x] # Add onto previously found sequence length
                break
        else:
            lengths[i] = len(list(collatz(i))) # Store full length of collatz sequence
    return max(lengths, key=lengths.get) # Key of memo with largest value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I wanted to say that you compute the sequence twice, which is one too many. But looking more carefully, the `else` part of the loop will only be reached the first time. Every other iteration will at least try to grab `lengths[1]`. So you could define `lengths = {1: 1}` and get rid of that special case.

Second, you only compute the length for the first element of the sequence at a time. For `collatz(3)` you know that the length is one more than `collatz(10)` which is one more than `collatz(5)` and so on. Why wait to compute these sequences to store their lengths when you could have done it when computing `collatz(3)`. For that, I propose you replace the body of the for loop with `collatz_length(collatz(i), lengths)` defined as:

```
def collatz_length(iterator, cache):
    n = next(iterator)
    try:
        return cache[n]
    except KeyError:
        cache[n] = value = 1 + collatz_length(iterator, cache)
        return value
```

Optionally, `lengths` could be a `collections.Counter` instead of a plain old dictionary. So you could use `lengths.most_common(1)` to get the longest sequence. But since `Counter` will return 0 for missing elements instead of raising `KeyError`, you will need:

```
def collatz_length(iterator, cache):
    n = next(iterator)
    if n not in cache:
        cache[n] = 1 + collatz_length(iterator, cache)
    return cache[n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n must be 0, 1, 2 ...
```

Should be:

```
n must be 1, 2, 3 ...
```

Or say that:

```
n must be a positive integer.
```

Your code doesn't give an infinite loop, but it doesn't make sense really that you return `[0]` for your function. If you "allowed" `0` the `collatz` funciton would return an infinite list of `0`s. (Why?)

Comment: Just looked up the collatz conjecture, you're right, they specify it has to be a positive integer